# How to rewrite both .php and .html files in IIS using url rewriting?

Tags: php, html, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am working on a server having both `.php` and `.html` extension files, and I wanted to hide their extension (for both `.php` and `.html` files).

For example: `www.xyz.com/abc.php` to `www.xyz.com/abc`
         and `www.xyz.com/gif.html` to `www.xyz.com/gif`

I am using IIS server so I am using URL Rewrite module of IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the file exists before rewriting, then it will go on to the next rule.
Something like this...

```
<rule name="rule 1W" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^\.]+)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/{R:1}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2W" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^\.]+)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/{R:1}.html" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.html"  />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="rule 1W" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([^\.]+)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php"  />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: This only works with .php files and not with .html ones , I need that <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php or {R:1}.html"> something like that so that if file is of any extension it wud work

Comment: yuou have to add another rule for .html like <rule name="rule 2W" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([^\.]+)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.html"  />
</rule>

Comment: Ya I Tried that same thing but rules are conflicting and thus only 1st rule is working , second one is not working, Suggest me any generic action url , such that it wud look for .php and if not found wud look for .html files

Comment: <rule name="rule 1c">
 <match url="^(.*)$"  />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.html"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2c">
 <match url="^(.*)$"  />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php"  />
</rule><rule name="rule 1c">
 <match url="^(.*)$"  />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.html"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2c">
 <match url="^(.*)$"  />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php"  />
</rule>